# Peace among countries or between countries?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

> A more comprehensive research program would look for historical cases
>   of stable peace between countries that are not democracies, or between
>   states only one of which is a democracy.

*Stable peace among nations*,
by Arie Marcelo Kacowicz

Here, the author discuss generally about all countries, why he use “between”. He is ruling out the possibilities like world war two? Or he is emphasizing the abstract structure of war:  two opponents, two polar opposites? According to N-gram, peace between countries is much more frequently used than peace among countries. What is your explanation?

Answer (score 1):

See the Usage Note at https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=between&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

While there is a "traditional rule" restricting *between* to talk about two things, actual "practice is mixed."

Answer (score 0):

*Between* refers to two countries, while *among* is better for three or more countries.

As for N-gram results, "peace between countries" referring to two nations might be more common than peace among three or more countries.